# Outputting errors to a different location than function called from

Tags: php, javascript

I have a functions.php file that I keep at the top of pages that looks out for POST requests and runs the appropriate function. The only trouble is I wan't to be able to output the errors to a different area of the page as they can't be seen at the moment. I want to keep the functions.php at the top of the page and output to a different place if this is possible? I was attempting to with javascript but I had no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Javascript is the way to go. Show what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly `functions.php` outputs error at the top of the page and you don't like it.

If so, then you could wrap in `div` a place where you call a function, I assume headers are already sent before/it's safe to output. Then you could use javascript to cut the contents of div if present and place it in appropriate places. You can even write a small help table for you where you specify function names and parse it so you could show messages at all the different places by simply moving them.

Another option is to use a custom error handler for your `functions.php`, assign outputs to `$_SESSION` and show on appropriate places. I'd stick with this one.